# Encryption inside oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

In dot net i can use dll file so that my code is safe from others. But is there any ways so that none can see the code of some of my procedures and triggers ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [wrap procedure code](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/wrap.htm#LNPLS01601) to make it unreadable.  You cannot wrap trigger code, but you can move the trigger code into a stored procedure so that the trigger code contains nothing more than a call to a wrapped procedure.

Comment: Not really "encryption" of course since it's not very difficult to reverse-engineer, but safe from the casual viewer.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following approach. 
**Note:** I have never tried this approach for hiding code, but could apply in your case.

1. create another schema with synonyms 
   that point to all required code from
   the original schema.
2. restrict access    to the original schema only from the    new schema,
   thus hiding code.
3. Use the    new schema for public access.

I have code that can create such a schema as a sample. Take a look and see if the approach works for you.

http://1smallthought.blogspot.com/2008/06/creating-shortcut-to-schema-using.html