# What kind of stored procedure is this one(curiosity)?

Tags: plsql

This is something I'm curious on. In my org's DB, we have some strange stored proc's that look like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure CTXSYS.dri_move_ctxsys wrapped
a000000
1
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
7
264c c53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```

/

What Is this  type of code for ? Encrypted or such?

Comment: This is the proprietary PL/SQL code of Oracle engine (notice the schema name `CTXSYS`) and thus it's hidden from your eyes. See the [A PL/SQL Source Text Wrapping](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/wrap.htm) chapter in PL/SQL Language Reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encryption inside oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859565/encryption-inside-oracle)

Comment: You're looking at 'WRAPPED' or encrypted procedure. [See this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/wrap.htm). Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, this is a object of type procedure and is encrypted .

If you would like encrypted your procedures you can use the program 'wrap' that is inside the bin directory.

It is used to encrypted objects, but it is not recommended by Oracle save any password or kind of that, because it possible decrypt.

Any question just let me know.

Thanks.