# How to encypt my stored procedure so that no one see

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Mostly PLSQL developer build a stored procedure so anyone can see the stored procedure so now I want to make it encrypt how its possible.

Now in our company most of them can see the stored procedure and make some changes.

My main intention is security purpose.

Please help.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/949248?tstart=0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encryption inside oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1859565/266304); but being able to see the source code and being able to modify it are very different things. Which are you really worried about?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it's not really possible - at least I don't know the easy way for that. You can use `wrap` utility but when your user is smart enough then the 
[UnwrapIt](http://www.codecrete.net/UnwrapIt) is even there online.

BTW. Th wrapping has some side effects - performance degradation..